# Trying to use autoremove

Tags: apt, package-management

When removing unused kernals (to make space on /boot) I get this message:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-mplayer hardinfo libgda-5.0-4 libgda-5.0-common libgmlib1 libgmtk1
  libgmtk1-data libmusicbrainz3-6 libwxsqlite3-3.0-0 linux-headers-3.19.0-30
  linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic lubuntu-default-session
  lubuntu-software-center lxappearance-obconf lxsession-default-apps mtpaint
  python-gudev python-pysqlite2 sylpheed-plugins transmission xpad
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 47 not to upgrade.
```

I don't understand the last line, and when I use the autoremove command as suggested I get:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What do I do?

Comment: Did you run the command as `sudo apt-get autoremove`?  The could not open lock file is usually because of no `sudo` in front of the command so it is ran as a `root` user.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get on Ubuntu always requires sudo.

You should copy paste this command into the terminal:

sudo apt-get autoremove